# Why doesn't my comparison in BASH work?

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare some characters in BASH

```
read a
if (($a == "Y"))
then
    echo "YES"
elif (($a == "y"))
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

but for some reason it does not work as expected. It always output YES. Looking at this super simple script, I can not understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's due to spacing and the brackets.

```
read a
if [[ $a == "Y" ]]
then
   echo "YES"
elif [[ $a == "y" ]]
then
   echo "YES"
else
   echo "NO"
fi
```

Comment: It's not due to spacing, it's due to the fact that they used parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: @whereswalden also the spacing matters even in brackets too. Sorry I forgot to specifiy both

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted. This is much better answer than already upvoted one. I clearly gives an answer together with an explanation. Thank you KRUKUSA

Comment: For my money, @whereswalden's pointer to TLDP.org is well worth the visit.

Answer (score 1):

You should review [bash comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html). You're trying to use an arithmetic expansion construct to do string comparison. Instead, you should use the `[ exp ]` or `[[ exp ]]` constructs.

Answer (score 0):

((expression)) is used for 'arithmetic evaluation' and strings inside (( )) will be treated as variable names, thus

if (($a == "Y"))

is equivalent to

if [ $a == $Y ]

(if $Y is a string, then bash will try to expand the name until it finds a numeric value or undefined variable)

You need to use [ ] or [[ ]] to compare strings as @KRUKUSA said.